# Create Database and User Script with variables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create a sql script that creates a database, a login with a password, and then adds that login to the database.

This is what I have so far. It fails when trying to execute the create login statement with the error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>
> Incorrect syntax near 'login1'.

I'm assuming it is failing because I need to put single quotes around the password, but I don't know how to do that. How can I fix this?

```
DECLARE @db varchar(50) = 'Database1';
DECLARE @userName varchar(50) = 'login1';
DECLARE @pwd varchar(50) = @userName;

DECLARE @createDb varchar(MAX);
DECLARE @createUser varchar(MAX);
DECLARE @useDb varchar(MAX);
DECLARE @addUserToTable varchar(MAX);
DECLARE @grantUserTablePrivileges varchar(MAX);


SET @createDb = 'CREATE DATABASE {DBNAME}';
SET @useDb = 'USE {DBNAME}';
SET @createUser = 'CREATE LOGIN {USERNAME} WITH PASSWORD = "{PWD}"';
SET @addUserToTable = 'CREATE USER {USERNAME} FOR LOGIN {USERNAME}';
SET @grantUserTablePrivileges =  'sp_addrolemember db_owner, {USERNAME}';

DECLARE @script varchar(MAX);

SET @script = REPLACE(@createDb, '{DBNAME}', @db);
PRINT(@script);
EXECUTE (@script);

SET @script = REPLACE(@createUser, '{USERNAME}', @userName);
SET @script = REPLACE(@script, '{PWD}', @pwd);
PRINT(@script);
EXECUTE (@script);

SET @script = REPLACE(@useDb, '{DBNAME}', @db);
PRINT(@script);
EXECUTE (@script);

SET @script = REPLACE(@addUserToTable, '{USERNAME}', @userName);
PRINT(@script);
EXECUTE (@script);

SET @script = REPLACE(@grantUserTablePrivileges, '{USERNAME}', @userName);
PRINT(@script);
EXECUTE (@script);
```

Comment: When you have errors in your code you should provide the error message in your question so others aren't trying to be a human sql server.

Comment: added, for your convenience

Comment: Do you want to know, that you can escape single quotes by doubling them (`''`)?

Comment: One thing you always need to do with dynamic sql is to look at the code BEFORE you ever try to execute it. Then you should also actually try to execute the code manually. When you do that you will see that you have invalid syntax in CREATE LOGIN. You can't use double quotes around your string literal.

Comment: Apparently I do want to know that I can escape single quotes by placing two. That's what I needed to do. Thank you.

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to put single quotes around the password

```
SET @createUser = 'CREATE LOGIN {USERNAME} WITH PASSWORD = "{PWD}"';
```

became

```
SET @createUser = 'CREATE LOGIN {USERNAME} WITH PASSWORD = ''{PWD}''';
```

and it worked.

Originally I had double quotes. I replaced the double quotes with two single quotes, in case it isn't clear.